# High seek error rate on new Seagate HDD

Tags: hard-drive, smart

We just got our new Seagate ST4000NE001-2MA101 4TB as a replacement for a dying disk. After copying the data from the old disk I had a look to the smart data of the new one and found high values for Seek Error Rate.

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR--   078   067   044    -    60289752
  3 Spin_Up_Time            PO----   099   099   000    -    0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   100   100   020    -    1
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         POSR--   064   060   045    -    2784938
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   100   100   000    -    32
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--C-   100   100   097    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   020    -    1
 18 Head_Health             PO-R--   100   100   050    -    0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
188 Command_Timeout         -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O---K   064   060   040    -    36 (Min/Max 19/40)
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    8
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   036   040   000    -    36 (0 19 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  -O-RC-   078   067   000    -    60289752
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--C-   100   100   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----C-   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -OSRCK   200   200   000    -    0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       ------   100   253   000    -    22h+21m+00.677s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      ------   100   253   000    -    5674319376
242 Total_LBAs_Read         ------   100   253   000    -    1968066
```

Is this normal for a brand new hard disk?
It's perhaps worth noting that the drive is connected via a slightly outdated SATA USB 2 adapter. Could this have an influence on these errors?

Comment: I don't think the raw value is meaningful for the seek error rate. My Seagate drive looks the same, so you should better stick with the value and the threshold and those values don't look bad: 64 current, 60  worse 45 threshold. See also [Why do all of my Seagates have such high seek error rates?](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/67bt11/why_do_all_of_my_seagates_have_such_high_seek/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the post
[Why do all of my Seagates have such high seek error rates? Should I be concerned?](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/67bt11/why_do_all_of_my_seagates_have_such_high_seek/)

> Seagate use a 48bit hex output for their RAW data values. You need to
> understand their output format, and then convert the raw values to
> determine the ACTUAL error rate.
>
> Seek Error Rate is a converted Hex value where the first 16 bits are
> the ACTUAL number of errors, and the last 32 bits are the total number
> of Seeks.
>
> Ignore the raw value and look at the threshold. The threshold
> indicates how many errors you've had over n seeks.

Going by this information, your value of 2784938 is less
than 32 bits, which means that this is the total number
of seeks done on the drive. You have zero seek *errors*
on the disk.

Reference given in the post (archived version) :
[Seagate's Seek Error Rate, Raw Read Error Rate, and Hardware ECC Recovered SMART attributes](https://web.archive.org/web/20120217031429/http://www.users.on.net/%7Efzabkar/HDD/Seagate_SER_RRER_HEC.html).